# Does Oracle 11gR2 actually support IPV6?

Tags: oracle, ipv6

Oracle has declared that 11g R2 has support IPV6 and ojdbc6.jar is the right one.

But when I test it, I get exception, have you solved that?

My test code is:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {

final static String sDBDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

/**
* @param args
* @throws SQLException 
*/

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
java.sql.Connection conn=null; 

String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=
[fe80::b056:5cff:fe78:b672])(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=fnstdb1))";

try
{
Class.forName(sDBDriver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"scott","fnst1234");
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
System.out.println("ERROR:"+e.getMessage()); 
} 
finally
{
System.out.println("连接是否关闭："+conn.isClosed());
conn.close();
}
}

}
```

and I use the following cmd:

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true Test
```

but the result is: `ERROR:NL Exception was generated`

What is wrong?

Comment: I guess it is worth mentioning that you have asked this question on [OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2389637) too.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: yes ,I have asked the question on the oracle forum ,I am sorry ,but I have been puzzled with it ,can anybody give me a question?

Comment: I have add the right paren in the url string,but also fail.java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Should I modify the oracle`s listners.ora?yes or no?

Comment: Is the database server Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem .the following shows what have I done:

## Procedure

1. edit `$DB_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora` file to allow the oracle to listen on the ip and port. for example: `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [fe80::221:97ff:fe66:1fa9%4])(PORT= 1521))`
2. Reatart the listener. Run: `LSNRCTL stop/start`
3. In some applications （javase, connection-pool, lookup）use ojdbc6.jar: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@[fe80::221:97ff:fe66:1fa9]:1521:orcl`.
4. The result is successful!!

## Demo

1. the ip address in listener.ora must add "%4" ,or it will fail.
2. ipv6 address must in "["and "]",or it will fail.
3. the document of oracle declares that using ipv6 must set the jvm options

   `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true`

but it does not matter whether it sets or not!